# Multiple GUID_partition_scheme, cant boot MacOS High Sierra, and gpt command resource busy

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

I have a problem after deleting Kali OS from my dual-boot Macbook (with High-Sierra MacOS). The problem is:

1. I can only boot into internet-recovery-mode
2. I can not use gpt command, as it results: 'resource busy'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition types got hosed by removing Kali Linux. Disk0s2 and disk0s3 got the wrong types. I would expect some Apple partition type for disk0s2 (HFS+/CoreStorage/APFS) and a Linux partition type for disk0s3. Disk0s4 is probably some dispensable Linux boot/swap partition.

To regain access to macOS you have to modify the partition type of disk0s2.

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- In the menubar open Terminal.app and enter:

  ```
  diskutil list
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```

  to get all partition and volume details of the internal SSD
- Unmount all disk0 related volumes and disks (in your example that's disk2 (based on disk0s3), disk0s4 and finally disk0). Examples: `diskutil unmountVolume disk0s4` or `diskutil unmountDisk disk0`.
- Remove the APFS container disk2: `diskutil ap deleteContainer disk2`
- Remove disk0s3 and disk0s4 (either with diskutil or gpt).
  Example: `diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Nil disk0s4`
- Determine the partition type of disk0s2 ([How can I make my Mac partition bootable again?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/319935/93229)) and remove and re-add disk0s2 using gpt with the same size but the proper type. Considering the macOS version (10.13) and the hardware (SSD) the proper partition type is probably 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (APFS) instead of FFFFFFFF-FFFF….
- Expand disk0s2 with `diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s2 0`.

---

Under certain circumstances you have to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) to edit the partition table with gpt!

Comment: thankyou, you saved my life. I do appreciate your help that solved my problem. Now I can boot normally without loosing any file.